# Regex to extract numbers and trailing letter or white space

Tags: r, regex

I'm currently trying to extract data from strings that are always in the same format (scraped from social sites with no API support)

*example of strings*

```
53.2k Followers, 11 Following, 1,396 Posts
5m Followers, 83 Following, 1.1m Posts
```

I'm currently using the following regex expression: 
"[0-9]{1,5}([,.][0-9]{1,4})?" to get the numeric sections, preserving the comma and dot separators.

*It yields results like*

```
53.2, 11, 1,396 
5, 83, 1.1
```

I really need a regular expression that will also grab the character after the numeric sections, even if it's a white-space. i.e.

```
53.2k, 11 , 1,396
5m, 83 , 1.1m
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

R code for reproduction

```
  library(stringr)

  string1 <- ("536.2k Followers, 83 Following, 1,396 Posts")
  string2 <- ("5m Followers, 83 Following, 1.1m Posts")

  info <- str_extract_all(string1,"[0-9]{1,5}([,.][0-9]{1,4})?")
  info2 <- str_extract_all(string2,"[0-9]{1,5}([,.][0-9]{1,4})?")

  info 
  info2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest the following regex pattern:

```
[0-9]{1,3}(?:,[0-9]{3})*(?:\\.[0-9]+)?[A-Za-z]*
```

This pattern generates the outputs you expect.  Here is an explanation:

```
[0-9]{1,3}      match 1 to 3 initial digits
(?:,[0-9]{3})*  followed by zero or more optional thousands groups
(?:\\.[0-9]+)?  followed by an optional decimal component
[A-Za-z]*       followed by an optional text unit
```

I tend to lean towards base R solutions whenever possible, and here is one using `gregexpr` and `regmatches`:

```
txt <- "53.2k Followers, 11 Following, 1,396 Posts"
m <- gregexpr("[0-9]{1,3}(?:,[0-9]{3})*(?:\\.[0-9]+)?[A-Za-z]*", txt)
regmatches(txt, m)

[[1]]
[1] "53.2k"   "11"   "1,396"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can add an optional character argument in the regex

```
stringr::str_extract_all(string1,"[0-9]{1,5}([,.][0-9]{1,4})?[A-Za-z]?")[[1]]
#[1] "536.2k" "83"     "1,396" 
stringr::str_extract_all(string2,"[0-9]{1,5}([,.][0-9]{1,4})?[A-Za-z]?")[[1]]
#[1] "5m"   "83"   "1.1m"
```

Answer (score 0):

(**Updated** my earlier post that selected extraneous commas/space)
This works to meet the OP's requirement to extract `trailing letter or white space after the numeric sections` (without the extraneous commas and white_spaces of my previous version):

> (?:[\d]+[.,]?(?=\d*)[\d]*[km ]?)

previous version: \b(?:[\d.,]+[km\s]?)

```
Explanation:  
- (?:          indicates non-capturing group
- [\d]+        matches 1 or more digits
- [.,]?(?=\d*) matches 0 or 1 decimal_point or comma that is immediately followed ("Positive Lookahead") by 1 or more digits
- [\d]*        matches 0 or more digits
- [km\s]?      matches 0 or 1 of characters within []
```

```
53.2k Followers, 11 Following, 1,396 Posts     
5m Followers, 83 Following, 1.1m Posts  
# 53.2k; 11 ; 1,396
# 5m; 83 ; 1.1m
```

note the spaces matched after 11 and 83, as intended by OP.

Answer (score 0):

Another `stringr` option:

```
new_s<-str_remove_all(unlist(str_extract_all(string2,"\\d{1,}.*\\w")),"[A-Za-z]{2,}")
strsplit(new_s," , ")

    #[[1]]
    #[1] "5m"    "83"    "1.1m "
```

**Original**

```
str_remove_all(unlist(str_extract_all(string2,"\\d{1,}\\W\\w+")),"[A-Za-z]{2,}")
#[1] "83 "  "1.1m"
str_remove_all(unlist(str_extract_all(string1,"\\d{1,}\\W\\w+")),"[A-Za-z]{2,}")
#[1] "536.2k" "83 "    "1,396"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you also want to grap the character after the numeric section even if it is a space, you could use your pattern and an optional character class `[mk ]?` including the space:

```
[0-9]{1,5}(?:[,.][0-9]{1,4})?[mk ]?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0lZGx9/1) | [R demo](https://ideone.com/0dR1Ph)

You might expand the range of characters in the the character class to match `[a-zA-Z ]?` instead. If you want to use a quantifier to match either 1+ times a char OR a single space you could use an alternation:

```
[0-9]{1,5}(?:[,.][0-9]{1,4})?(?:[a-zA-Z]+| )?
```